# Flask Requests.Args works in local machine although not on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have made a simple flask app that collects data from the arguments in URL and puts them into a python module which sends output in Json format which works fine on Local machine although gives error when deployed to Heroku . The error message says nothing other than TIMEOUT ERROR. Here is the heroku link for deployed app - https://shodhapi.herokuapp.com/ Here's Code

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date 

import pandas as pd

from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask import request

config = {
    "CACHE_TYPE": "SimpleCache",  # Flask-Caching related configs
    "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 300,
}

app = Flask(__name__)
# tell Flask to use the above defined config
app.config.from_mapping(config)
cache = Cache(app)


@app.route("/api")
@cache.cached(timeout=600)
def index():
    ticker = request.args.get( 'ticker', None)
    sy = int(request.args.get('sy', None))
    sm = int(request.args.get('sm', None))
    sd = int(request.args.get('sd', None))
    ey = int(request.args.get('ey', None))
    em = int(request.args.get('em', None))
    ed = int(request.args.get('ed', None))

    # 2022,1,31
    results = get_history(symbol=ticker,start=date(sy,sm,sd),end=date(ey,em,ed))
    results.reset_index(inplace=True)
    results.set_index('Deliverable Volume', inplace=True)
    results['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(results['Date'])

    # convert dataframe to json
    result_json = results.to_json(orient="records")
    return result_json


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the heroku deployed app along with the build log shown on the heroku website.

Comment: Here is the link - https://shodhapi.herokuapp.com/

Comment: How are you accessing your server on local machine? I mean at what address?

Comment: 404 error on link

Comment: Check the code u will have to go to Shodhapi.herokuapp.com/api to access it

Comment: I use this address on my local machine http://127.0.0.1:5500/api?ticker=IEX&sy=2022&sy=2022&sm=1&sd=1&ey=2022&em=1&ed=31

Answer (score 0):

I am not an everyday flask user, but have deployed some Nodejs servers to heroku. In Nodejs, although it uses a default port of 3000, you have to first check if the heroku environment provides an environment variable called `PORT`. Then you have to make your server listen at that port.(If no such variable is provided then you can listen on the default Nodejs port i.e., 3000).

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

In flask, you should probably do something like

```
import os
app.run(debug=True, port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5500)))
```

assuming 5500 is the default port for flask.

Comment: Tried using this with default port for flask which is 5000. Although its still not working . This is the url that i am using - https://shodhapi.herokuapp.com/api?ticker=IEX&sy=2022&sy=2022&sm=1&sd=1&ey=2022&em=1&ed=31

Comment: Post heroku logs. Depending on how you are deploying, either using `heroku logs --tail` if you are using command line or from the heroku portal/dashboard if you are using some other method like github.

Comment: This is the output of Heroku Logs --tail - 2022-05-24T17:30:40.188615+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api?ticker=IEX&sy=2022&sy=2022&sm=1&sd=1&ey=2022&em=1&ed=31" host=shodhapi.herokuapp.com request_id=ef881a5a-42df-4fe2-951c-5d5fc2eebd0d fwd="123.201.214.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 
protocol=https
2022-05-24T17:30:40.818186+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-24 17:30:40 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:49)

Comment: Is the build output in heroku dash board showing everything successful?

Comment: Its the output when i GET request from the URL - https://shodhapi.herokuapp.com/api?ticker=IEX&sy=2022&sy=2022&sm=1&sd=1&ey=2022&em=1&ed=31